# How to center text of button with Widget.Holo.Light:Spinner Style

Tags: android, xml

i would like to center the text of a button, which is styled as a Spinner Element. 
First element is centered cuz its actually a spinner.

Thx in advance. :)

XML:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_picksnoozetime"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" 
        android:textAlignment="center"           
        />
```

[image: Capture]

Comment: try android:gravity = "center".

Comment: That did the tick... Sry that was to easy :D

Comment: Accept my answer if helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android:gravity = "center"` in the Button. For more info [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)